# Distinguish 1 from True in python 3.8

Tags: python-3.8

I have some code where I want to do different things if a particular input variable is 1 vs True.  (In short numbers refer to which of several objects to do something on, and True means do it to all the objects, but that's not particularly relevant to this question.)

Currently, I used more or less the equivalent of:

```
if x is True:
   # Do something
elif x is 1:
   # Do something else
else:
   # More possibilities follow...
```

But in Python 3.8, I'm now getting

```
SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
```

Well, no I didn't.  Using `==` doesn't distinguish `True` and `1`, since `True == 1` in python.

But it sounds like the python devs think using `is` with a literal is [always a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue34850). It's just a warning, not an error, so I'm still fine for now, but what is the non-buggy way to do this that I should switch to?

Comment: Have you tried `True is x`?

Comment: I don't like warnings like this. It means you have a more complicated and probably undocumented syntax. The rule shouldn't say: "you can insert any term here, _unless_ it has the following form". If a variable is acceptable, a literal should be too.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out.  (Sorry to answer my own question.)

It turns out that the warning was just on the integer, not on `True`.  It seems to be still ok to write `if x is True`, but not `if x is 1`.  And once the former possibility is out of the way, the latter can safely use `==`.

So I think the correct form of this is

```
if x is True:
   # Do something
elif x == 1:
   # Do something else
else:
   # More possibilities follow...
```

Comment: Interesting... you said that `True == 1`. That means if you'd written `if x == 1:` at the start, it would have done the wrong thing when `x` was `True`.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Yes.  If you test `if x == 1` first, then that would get `True` too, which isn't what I want.  So order matters in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps cleaner than your mixed approach would be to *explicitly test the type*:

```
>>> type(1) == bool
False
>>> type(1) == int
True
>>>
>>> type(True) == bool
True
>>> type(True) == int
False
```